# Convert UWP to WebApp

Tags: web-applications, uwp

Is there a way to convert a UWP to run as a WebApp?

I don't have a developer account to submit a project so I have to find a way to run this app I created, but it is a UWP.

I understand that I can sideload, but then I would have to load the program myself on every computer, I think.

The problem I am running into is the security certificate.

Comment: you can't do that , but I think you should have a look at this: https://platform.uno/

Comment: The new Microsoft packaging tool MSIX helps you to publish your app to public without developer account. You can then use msix package of your application to spread over the website.

Comment: try this https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NBLGGH51S0C

Comment: MSIX would have been great if the company had pushed out a later build of Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, after much more research, that I had to install the certificate to the Trusted People store on the local machine.

Then I had to go into the dependencies folder and run all of the files there.

Then I could install the app.

After installation, I pin the app to the start menu.

Then I dragged the tile into the C:/Users/Public/Public Desktop (hidden) folder.

Now the app is available to all who use that machine.